# Highlight a cell based on text input in another in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a table with a column B6 - B24. This contains company names.

Another column G6 - G24 with notes.

I would like a formula that would highlight a company name(column B) if the text "call off" is written in notes.

Any ideas?

Also these columns might grow so would there be a way of having a formula that applied to the entire column?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Conditional Formatting option in Excel, its located in the home tab in 'Styles' section.
here is a good [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTztUryXNx0) from youtube that can help you get things started.
You can format your cells however you like according to the conditions your create.

Comment: Well, at least in Excel 2007, you cannot do all the things in conditional formatting that you can do in normal formatting.  For example, you cannot change font or font size, or alignment (left/center/right/top/middle/bottom).  But you can change text color, font style (bold/italic/underline), and fill color, so Jeremy has several options to “highlight” his company names.

Answer (score 1):

Apply conditional formatting to column B and set the formatting to change the cell color when it detects "call off" in the next cell. I don't have Excel available at the moment, so I can't tell you exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2010 you can make the data a table which will give allow the formatting to grow with the table. To add to the table, simply type data into the next row down and the table will automatically include it and format it.

**Here's how:**

Highlight your data, (assuming B6 to G24) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to insert the table. In the next window, choose the check-box if your table has headers. Click OK.

Now with the table still selected, from the `Home Ribbon` choose `Conditional Formatting > New Rule` then choose `Use formula to determine which cells to format`. In the formula box enter `=G6="call off"`.

[image]

Click OK twice to save the rule. This will highlight the cell in column B if the cell in column G has the words "call off".

[image]